# CSRF-cookie not set when sending a Delete request

Tags: django

I'm using django rest fro backend and reactnative for front, on my backend i have two models one for image and one for files, i can delete the files with a delete request but when i try to delete an image i get 403 forbidden crf cookie not set.

Image view:

```js
def UploadsDetails(request,pk):
    try:
        image=Uploads.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Uploads.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)
    if request.method =='DELETE':
        image.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

urls:

```js
from django.urls import path
from .views import  Upload_list,login
from .views import UploadsDetails

urlpatterns=[
    path('Uploads/',Upload_list),
    path('Uploads/<uuid:pk>/',UploadsDetails),
    path('login/', login)
]
```

the files view :

```js
def FileDetails(request,pk):
    try:
        file=File.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except File.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)
    if request.method =='GET':
        serializers=Fileserializers(file)
        return JsonResponse(serializers)
    elif request.method =='PUT':
        serializer=Fileserializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save()
           return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors,status=404)
    elif request.method =='DELETE':
        file.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Comment: You need to send the csrf back from the front-end when you send the delete request

Comment: How come i only need to send it for this specific request? all other requests i m sending are passing fine except for this one